# How to pass a New Line Character in XML

Tags: sql, xml

I have some data which I pass and save to my DB.

I convert the new line character `'\n'` to `<br>` before passing to My DB.

Now my database table column which accepts this string is in `XML` format and throws the following Error

```
XML parsing: line 1, character 25, well formed check: no '<' in attribute value
```

So obviously this wont work. How can i replace this with a new new line Character that XML will recognise?

Answer (score 0):

One way I think of doing it is by placing the `<br>` in `<![CDATA]]>`.

This is how it would look like:

```
<![CDATA[<br />]]>
```